# Emacs: how to set margins to automatically adjust when in split-screen?

Tags: emacs, margins

I am a historian trying to configure Emacs to efficiently write academic papers. With that aim in mind, I decided to add margins to the Emacs buffer. The end result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zts2j.png), and was achieved with this code:

```
;; Margins function

(defun my-set-margins ()
  "Set margins in current buffer."
  (setq left-margin-width 26)
  (setq right-margin-width 26))

;; Add margins by default to a mode

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-set-margins)
```

The problem is that when I split the screen vertically, the margins make the text unreadable. So, I came to the conclusion that it would be necessary to either (1) have Emacs remove the margins automatically during vertical split screen and put them back when in single screen; or (2) create a keyboard shortcut to toggle the margins. Any elips ideas on how to do either? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are just too many possibilities that occur when windows are split to write up a *general* solution based thereon, so I chose the second option which is a simple toggle.  You could just write your own function that splits a window in a specified direction and then set the margins, and another function to `delete-other-windows` and then set margins.

Comment: E.g.:  `(defun foo () "Doc-string." (interactive) (delete-other-windows) (setq left-margin-width 0) (setq right-margin-width 0) (set-window-buffer (selected-window) (current-buffer)))`

Comment: As you have discovered, configuring a static value for a particular window geometry doesn't work well when the geometry is in fact dynamic.  I suggest you remove the binding from the hook, and invoke it manually when you are in a situation where you want this behavior.  Maybe add a second function to reset it back to default for when you wish to resize your window.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62911403/324105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states that setting the `left-margin-width` or `right-margin-width` does not immediately affect the window.  These variables are checked when a new buffer is displayed in the window. Thus, you can make changes take effect by calling `set-window-buffer`.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Margins.html

The following function checks to see whether either margin is greater than 0, and toggles either on or off based thereon.  I bound the interactive function to the `global-map` with the `f5` key.

```lisp
(defun my-toggle-margins ()
"Set margins in current buffer."
(interactive)
  (if (or (> left-margin-width 0) (> right-margin-width 0))
    (progn
      (setq left-margin-width 0)
      (setq right-margin-width 0)
      (set-window-buffer (selected-window) (current-buffer)))
    (setq left-margin-width 26)
    (setq right-margin-width 26)
    (set-window-buffer (selected-window) (current-buffer))))

(global-set-key [f5] 'my-toggle-margins)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have been using your solution for some time, and it integrates perfectly into my workflow!

Comment: I see that we can move `(set-window-buffer (selected-window) (current-buffer))` after the **IF/THEN** statement, since it is called in either circumstance.  That way, it only needs to appear one time.  It's not necessary to do that, but it would look better.