# Emacs continuation lines before screen edge

Tags: emacs

I would like Emacs to display a line continuation at a specified column -- say column 80 -- rather than at the edge of the screen. Is this possible? I know that I can use `visual-line-mode` and possibly configure that to soft-break the lines at some pre-defined width, but I prefer working on logical lines and would therefore prefer not to use `visual-line-mode`.

Comment: See also: https://codeberg.org/joostkremers/visual-fill-column

Comment: See also: https://github.com/rnkn/olivetti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the window margins more or less does this, but it's going to cause some problems (at minimum, it can interfere with splitting windows).

If you want to dig deeper, this might be a starting point.

```el
(defvar my-right-margin-column 80
  "Used by `my-right-margin-update'.")

(defun my-right-margin-update ()
  "Make the right margin occupy all space beyond `my-right-margin-column'.

See `my-right-margin-auto-update'."
  (set-window-margins
   nil 0 (max 0 (- (+ (window-text-width)
                      (or (cdr (window-margins)) 0))
                   my-right-margin-column)))
  (set-window-parameter nil 'min-margins '(0 . 0)))

(defun my-right-margin-auto-update ()
  "Configure buffer-local `window-configuration-change-hook'."
  (add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook
            #'my-right-margin-update nil :local))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'my-right-margin-auto-update)
```

Comment: That was fairly straight-forward. Thanks for the inspiration. I wonder if you already have an idea what kind of issues it may cause.

Comment: Things I noticed playing with that were (a) showing the same buffer in multiple windows of different widths got things pretty confused (margins are for buffers rather than windows), and (b) splitting windows became problematic.

Comment: I've updated the code to use window margins, which solves (a) but not (b).

Comment: `C-h i g (elisp)Window Parameters` indicates that splitting is accounted for by the window parameter `min-margins`, which was added to support your use-case, essentially.  See also https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24193.  I've added a usage of that which... mostly works?  You might need to rebalance windows after splitting.  The manual also suggests that `window-size-change-functions` is going to be slightly more reliable than `window-configuration-change-hook`.

Comment: I also note the mysterious and completely unsubstantiated "Turns out there is a better solution" at the end of that bug thread.  It would have been nice if they had elaborated.

Comment: The referenced (in that bug discussion) https://github.com/rnkn/olivetti might be a more robust solution for you, or provide answers to other issues you encounter.

Comment: Wow. You really went above and beyond! Thank you so much. It would've taken me quite some time to figure out the finer details of this. It's also a nice snippet to dive a bit deeper into elisp. Cheers! Olivetti looks pretty neat as well. I'll have a look at that!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll note that as of Emacs 27, there are a lot of new hooks for the various different kinds of window change.  In 26 we have `window-size-change-functions` and `window-configuration-change-hook`; whereas 27 adds `window-buffer-change-functions`, `window-selection-change-functions`, `window-state-change-functions`, and `window-state-change-hook`.  See `C-h i g (elisp)Window Hooks` for all of the details.